# You must provide the URL of lib/mappings.wasm by calling SourceMapConsumer.initialize({ 'lib/mappings.wasm': ... }) before using SourceMapConsumer

Tags: angular

I'm facing the above error when building a project (Angular 8). How can we fix this error?

Comment: Whoever runs into any similarly worded error should fix the actual issues rather than use the hacks below. In my case i ran an `npm update`.

Answer (score 7):

`$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--no-experimental-fetch"`

Run this command in Visual Studio Code in power shell, this will fix the problem ISA.

Comment: FYI this is in power shell

Answer (score 5):

I get the same problem when building a ts-project.

### The problem

It is a problem with the source-map package release 0.7.3
This version of the source-map package detects the environment by looking for the "fetch" function.
Since the fetch function is available in Node.js version 18, sourcemap thinks it is running in a browser (and throws the error)

This is fixed in source-map version 0.7.4.

### The solution

The solutions proposed by nuander and Mohammed Osman will probably work to some extend, depending on your project.

My proposed solution:

Add an [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json?v=true#overrides) field to your package.json:

```
"overrides":{
   "foo":{
     "source-map": "0.7.4"
   }
 }
```

Where foo is the package dependent on the fault source-map package.

This solved it for me.

NB: the resolutions field is only supported in npm version 8.3.0 or higher. If you are using an earlier version of npm, the overrides field will be ignored.

Comment: This is the less hacky solution, indeed, but as stated by JGallardo in his comment on the question it is not ideal...

Comment: I totally agree, but not all of us have the luxury to run npm update

Comment: This didn't work for me. I read into the issue on github and some people seemed to say that upgrading their version of source-map had resolved the issue. It didn't work for me either...

Answer (score 1):

My internet research lead to indications that this is an issue in newer versions of node. Setting NODE_OPTIONS as suggested did not help. Downgrading to an earlier version fixed this for me.

Comment: What version did you downgrade to?